# Regex to extract phone number in complex text

Tags: python, regex

I spent a lot of time to write a regex to match the following strings:

```
tel/mob: 001 433 123 4352
tel/mob: 0014331234352
tel: 001 433 123 4352
tel: 0014331234352
tel/mob: 001 (433) 123 4352
tel: 001 (433) 123 4352
tel/mob: +1 433 123 4352
tel/mob: +14331234352
tel: +1 433 123 4352
tel: +14331234352
tel/mob: +1 (433) 123 4352
tel: +1 (433) 123 4352
```

What I did is:

```
print (re.findall(r':\s(\w+)' , article))
```

But it does not work properly, I need to extract numbers.

Comment: Could you show us fragment of the file? Are the numbers in separate lines or somewhere in the text?

Comment: Or even, are they all preceded by `tel/mob` or `tel`?

Comment: @h4z3 sometimes in separate lines and sometimes they are somewhere in the text

Comment: Just split on `': '`.

Comment: Is the problem just the +? testing your regex the only issue on this data is the plus. If you have other issues please post text example to illustrate.

Comment: wait nvmind I see whitespace is an issue as well

Comment: `r'(tel|mob): (\+|00)([ \(\)]*\d){11}'` - gets `tel:`/`mob:`, then `+`/`00`, then 11 following digits, with spaces, `(` and `)` in any place. Works for all presented cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about taking everything after the `:`, that is ether a digit, space, plus or bracket ?

```
import re

data = """tel/mob: 001 433 123 4352
tel/mob: 0014331234352
tel: 001 433 123 4352
tel: 0014331234352
tel/mob: 001 (433) 123 4352
tel: 001 (433) 123 4352
tel/mob: +1 433 123 4352
tel/mob: +14331234352
tel: +1 433 123 4352
tel: +14331234352
tel/mob: +1 (433) 123 4352
tel: +1 (433) 123 4352"""

for line in data.splitlines():
    m = re.search(r':([0-9() +]+)', line)
    print ''.join(c for c in m.groups()[0] if c.isdigit())
```

Output:

```
0014331234352
0014331234352
0014331234352
0014331234352
0014331234352
0014331234352
14331234352
14331234352
14331234352
14331234352
14331234352
14331234352
```

https://regex101.com/r/QYSlJj/1

Answer (score 1):

I've allowed an optional + sign at the start, and repeating groups of numbers, and optional parenthesis. Works on supplied examples.

```
r':\s\+?(\(?[0-9]+\)?\s?)+'
```

https://regex101.com/r/ugQU0D/1

Comment: it does not contain strings that have spaces within, like 001 433 123 4352

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: For example, for a number like 001 4331234352 it just matches 43312344352 and 001 is not match

Comment: @Mahdi first, it does match 001 43312352. Check in the link. Second, if you are going to ask a question about regexes you must put all the examples you want to match. I can't guess what else is in your data.